# segmentation fault without (core dumped)

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, ubuntu-18.04, coredump

I'm running a fortran program on ubuntu 18.04, and got a segmentation fault but no core generated. I've already tried the previous suggestion as below:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid
echo "core" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
ulimit -c unlimited
```

here is the result:

```
root@goodluck:# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15415
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15415
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
root@goodluck:# gdb LPDM_gnu_omp 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1.1-0ubuntu1) 8.1.1
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/yufei/LPDM/work/democode/LPDM_gnu_omp 
During startup program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

but the core file still not generated, and when I got the segmentation fault, I didn't get this

```
segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

instead I got this:

```
segmentation fault
```

Could someone help me? I searched all the internet but got no clues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the working directory writable?

Comment: what happens when you use `gdb LPDM_gnu_omp` and give here the `run` command?

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Cut/paste text instead.

Comment: @Ronald yes, it is writable for both user and root.

Comment: @albert I got SIGSEGV during startup program, as I reposted above.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks for your suggestion and I've made it modified.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible reasons a `core` may not be generated:

1. The directory into which the `core` would have been generated is not writable, or on a read-only filesystem, or on a full filesystem.
2. The program disabled `core` generation by calling `setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {0, 0})` (undoing `ulimit -c unlimited`), or calling `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0)` [description](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html).

There might be other reasons as well. I suggest verifying that `/tmp` is not full, and trying to dump a `core` there.

If that still doesn't work, probably `ulimit(2)`, `prlimit64` or `prctl(2)` is to blame. Run the program under `strace -e ulimit,prlimit64,prctl` to confirm.

If you are just looking for "why is the program crashing", you don't (usually) need a `core` -- you could run the program directly under debugger, e.g.

```
gdb LPDM_gnu_omp
(gdb) run
... what for crash, GDB will stop
(gdb) where
```

**Update:**

> What does it mean for a Fortran program to "call `ulimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {0, 0})`"
> If I gave my Fortran compiler the "program" call `ulimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {0, 0})`; end I'd be surprised to get something back that I can run

You are asking about the *mechanics* of invoking a `C` function from Fortran, while my answer is about the *conceptual* reason why you may be left without a `core`.

For mechanics, you would need to look at your Fortran implementation documentation, e.g. GCC Fortran<->C interface is defined [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperable-Subroutines-and-Functions.html).

P.S. the `ulimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {0, 0})` is not a valid `C` either, it's a shorthand for:

```
  struct rlimit r;
  r.rlim_min = r.rlim_max = 0;
  setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &r);
```

P.P.S. I mis-remembered the `ulimit(3)` interface -- I meant `setrlimit(2)` everywhere I used `ulimit` above. I fixed the uses.

Comment: What does it mean for a Fortran program to "call `ulimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {0, 0})`"?

Comment: @francescalus Typically any Fortran program depends on `libc`, and may call any function from it. Ultimately, `ulimit(2)` or `prlimit64(2)` system call may be invoked.

Comment: In the context of a Fortran program, though, what does "calling `ulimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {0, 0})`" mean. That's not Fortran, regardless of whether any Fortran program depends on libc.

Comment: @francescalus It means calling the `C` routine `ulimit(3)`. Is your question about what that would do? It would be equivalent to executing `ulimit -c 0` at the shell prompt.

Comment: If I gave my Fortran compiler the "program" `call ulimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {0, 0}); end` I'd be surprised to get something back that I can run.

Comment: @francescalus I've updated the answer.